# Groupbox 1 or 2; Based on which Checkbox is chosen after Button Click

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-2010

On the form I have two groupboxes, two checkboxes and one button. In the button code, I am currently having the following two lines:

```
if CheckBox1.Checked then GroupBox1.Show; 
if CheckBox2.Checked then GroupBox2.Show;
```

What I would like to have is; after I click button,

> IF checkbox1 is checked then groupbox1 should appear and IF checkbox2
>   is checked then groupbox2 should appear.

However there are two further requirements that are confusing me:

1. Neither of two groupbox should be shown on the form before I press the mentioned button.
2. Both groupboxes (as said, which one appears depends on which
   checkbox is chosen after button click) should appear on the exact
   same location of the form. But I cannot set on exact location two
   different elements (in my case groupboxes).

`Version of delphi is 7.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Neither of two groupbox should be shown on the form

set .Visible to false in Delphi Object Inspector before u compile the program

Did you read help on .Show ? it mentions that property. look SEE ALSO section
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.Show

Frankly, more laconic would be listbox.visible := checkbox.checked

---

> should appear on the exact same location of the form

Well, you cannot show them at the same time at the same place ?

How do you want to show them BOTH if BOTH the checkboxes are on ?

I believe you should remove checkboxes and put radiobuttons instead that only one or another can be pressed.

Try the TRadioGroup

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.ExtCtrls.TRadioGroup.ItemIndex

```
 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 |  ( )   No lists |
 |  (*)   List 1   |
 |  ( )   List 2   |
 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

RadioGrououp.OnClick  := ... (* 
 procedure  ....
    List1.Visible := RadioGroup.ItemIndex = 1;
    List2.Visible := RadioGroup.ItemIndex = 2;
 end. *)

---

> Both groupboxes should appear on the exact same location

1) Use TNotebook and place them on different pages. Switch pages instead of toggling visibility. That approach would allow you make many more controls, not only those. And you can palce them at same coords on different pages easily.

2) in form.OnShow:  List2.Top := List1.Top and same for Left, Width and Height

Comment: I replaced both checkboxes with two radiobuttons but neither of the following two codes work:

`GroupBox1.Visible := RadioButton1.Checked;
GroupBox2.Visible := RadioButton2.Checked;
`

or

`GroupBox1.Visible := False;
 GroupBox2.Visible := False;
 if RadioButton1.ItemIndex = 0 then
  GroupBox1.Visible := True
 else
  GroupBox2.Visible := True;
 end;˙

Comment: read documentation and tutorials about radiobuttons and their behavior.  Or just use *radiogroup* - much easier and enouth for ur case

Comment: and where u put that code to ??? place there a breakpoint and see i that code ever gets executed ? if the codde is never executed - it can never change anything. I told you above both the code and which event should call it for *radiogroup*

Comment: I cannot use radiogroup because one of two groupboxes have to occur based on which radiobutton is pressed AFTER button click but with using either of those two codes, I cannot even run the software - its some wird error.

Comment: which button ?
make button disable radiogroup so that no one can click radiogroup before button pressed

Comment: or: http://pastebin.com/GfXyu3cf I don't disable before button pressed. This would be a way way too complicated. Im already having problems with those two topics: hidden at start + shown based on which radiobutton is clicked after button click AND same location for both groupboxes

Comment: code looks too long (actually two lines are enough)

did it ever called ?
what is the error ?

Comment: what about TNotebook ? u can make three pages - empty, with group1 and with group2

Comment: Error Undeclared identifier ItemIndex. TLama yes and on the same location.

Comment: @TLama how he could show BOTH boxes in the same coordinates at same time ? :-)

Comment: because button have no item index - it just has no items. radioGROUP has items and has itemindex. For radiobuttons you should have special setup that one radiobutton would clear another one.

Comment: they still aren't hidden and don't show as per requirement. Also not on same position.

Comment: Arioch The are you still here?

Comment: Now I managed to make them (them = two groupboxes) hidden on Run and also to show them AFTER button click based on which radiobutton is checked but no success yet with having them on same area of form. No idea what does TNoteBook mean

Comment: did u changed their coordinates as i shown ? try it in TForm.OnShow then

Comment: The user with username Whiler showed me where should I make the coordinates. Its logical that both groupboxes should have the same coordinates if I want them (=groupboxes) on the same area of form. But I don't have such form code anywhere. So I cannot change the coordinates as Whiler showed. Regarding OnShow event, there is no such thing in Object Inspector\Events.

Comment: put there ONE group box
in TForm.OnShow mover 2nd box into the place of the 1st. 

That was described at bottom on my answer.

Comment: And frankly, i consider using of Notebook easier better than manual toggling with all those properties

Comment: focus on the form itself, not any of the controls on it.
focus on the FORM! there is OnShow

Comment: Ok what I have done is that I physically moved one groupbox after another. The fact that showing one groupbox only (based on which radiobutton is checked after button click) already successfully worked further means that on this exact area will be now showed only one groupbox. I used to run it and, assuming that both groupboxes have the same sized, it worked good. I didn't use TForm.Onshow anywhere but it worked. Thank you Arioch even if I didn't completely follow your suggestion about TForm.Onshow but you probably meant something like I described also.

Comment: not exactly. If by any chance you would move one groupbox - you would have to again find how to move another
With my approach you only need tpo move 1st one - the second one ALWAYS would in runtime follow the 1st. no matter what you do.
but anyway, if it now works for you mark the question answered please

Comment: Ok clicked the Tick button to accept the answer. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
GroupBox1.Visible := CheckBox1.Checked;
GroupBox2.Visible := CheckBox2.Checked;
```

Comment: doesn't work. both groupboxes are still not hidden on the run, still not on the exact same area of form

Comment: change the visible in IDE before u compile the program  /// any property u change in IDE u can change in code after program been run. Most properties u change in code u can change in IDE before program beencompiled

Answer (score 1):

As your 2 GroupBox are at the same position, I'd use radiobutton instead of checkbox as the 2 groupbox can't be displayed at the same time...

Here is an example:

```
// Click event for a radiogroup see DFM below
procedure TForm1.rg1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  gb1.Visible := False;
  gb2.Visible := False;
  if rg1.ItemIndex = 0 then
    gb1.Visible := True
  else
    gb2.Visible := True;
end;
```

The form is designed like this (you can look the different properties I set):

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form6'
  ClientHeight = 337
  ClientWidth = 635
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object gb1: TGroupBox
    Left = 40
    Top = 60
    Width = 185
    Height = 105
    Caption = 'gb1'
    TabOrder = 0
    Visible = False
  end
  object gb2: TGroupBox
    Left = 40
    Top = 60
    Width = 185
    Height = 105
    Caption = 'gb2'
    TabOrder = 1
    Visible = False
  end
  object rg1: TRadioGroup
    Left = 40
    Top = 8
    Width = 185
    Height = 33
    Caption = 'rg1'
    Columns = 2
    Items.Strings = (
      'GB1'
      'GB2')
    TabOrder = 2
    OnClick = rg1Click
  end
end
```